# Dynamically resize iframes in a cross-domain site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to dynamically resize iframes based on content size from the parent. I have access to both the parent (source) and child (target) websites/servers.

However, they are cross-domain servers. They both are on different domains. I don't really know how to use jQuery. Is there perhaps an easy to follow tutorial?

Comment: I would pass the size of the parent iframe to the child using get parameters and load the iframe using js

Comment: Like I said, I am new to this, and I dont know how to.Can you please tell me how to? I am embedding www.a.com into www.b.com.

Comment: [See this article](http://pipwerks.com/2008/11/30/iframes-and-cross-domain-security-part-2/) - shows a trick that involves creating a frame inside of the frame. So `www.b.com` has iframe that points to `www.a.com` that has iframe whose url is generated via javascript that points back to `www.b.com/setsize.php?height=XXX&width=XXX` -- `XXX` being the width/height of the document on `www.b.com` (whether scrollHeight, bodyHeight, etc.), and then script on setsize.php can do stuff like `top.document.getElementById("myIframe").style.height='500px;'`

Comment: see my answer hope you can deal with it.

Comment: You've said "please help" and "urgent" in a bunch of questions. Please stop doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the iframe resizer jquery plugin. It works for me.

Just download these js files:

- [jquery-1.11.1.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js)
- [IframeResizer.js](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/blob/master/src/iframeResizer.js)
- [IframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/blob/master/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js)

In your **www.ADomain.com** add this code block in the page that has the iframe.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="iframeresizer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="iframeresizer.contentwindow.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#IframeID').iFrameResize({
            autoResize: true,
            enablePublicMethods: false,
            sizeWidth: false,
            heightCalculationMethod: 'bodyScroll'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then in your **www.BDomain.com** add this code block in the page that will be loaded to the iframe to avoid hitting that anoying error called *"sometimes my iframe is not resizing"*. This will create an instance of the resizer.

1. Put this jquery library inside the `<head> </head>` part of your page.

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>`
2. Put this line in the last part of your code before the `</body>`

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="iframeresizer.contentwindow.min.js">`

Hope this will help you. Good luck bro!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure maybe you can accomplish this using only css, but in the case you want to transfer information between iframes that both you have access to and to avoid cross domain errors you can transfer the data in url and process them using JS and JQUERY
lets assume this file is the main index.html

```
<iframe src="www.a.com/?width=330&height=220"></iframe>
```

this the code from index of a iframe

```
<iframe src="www.b.com"></iframe> 
   <script>


function getParam(name) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
          results = regex.exec(location.search);
  return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
    $(function(){
           $('iframe[src="www.b.com"]').width(getParam('width')).height(getParam('height')) 
    });
    </script>
```